# Android: How to make horizontal progress bar using Interpolator?

Tags: android, linear-interpolation

I have a progress bar view like this:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:max="100"/>
```

It lasts 3 second, so how to use interpolator to make update smoothly?

```
ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(what_is_in_here?); 
animation.setDuration(3000); //  second
animation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
animation.start();
```

I really appreciate your help. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 37):

I found out the solution:

```
progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(progressBar, "progress", 100, 0);
animation.setDuration(3500); // 3.5 second
animation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
animation.start();
```

Here is a detailed explanation:

create an animation object:

```
ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(progressBar, "progress", 100, 0);
```

- **progressBar**: reference to the ProgressBar in the layout;
- **"progress"**: the name of the property to be animated;
- **100:** starting point of the animation;
- **0:** ending point of the animation.

and set an interpolation:

```
animation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
```

It is possible to use different interpolators for our animation, like for example:

- **LinearInterpolator:** where the rate of change is constant.
- **DecelerateInterpolator:** where the rate of change starts out quickly and and then decelerates.
- **AccelerateInterpolator:** where the rate of change starts out slowly and and then accelerates.
- **OvershootInterpolator:** where the change flings forward and overshoots the last value then comes back.
- For other interpolators check the interface [android.view.animation.Interpolator.](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/view/animation/Interpolator.html)

Comment: Great Answer! Simple, clean and comprehensible.  Thank you!

Comment: need on help    "progress"  is property name already defined or custom ? if already define what are list of predefined